# How can I render the components after useEffect hook is finished?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, components

I'm fetching data from an api, and I have a hook which stores the data. I want to render the components after the useEffect hook has fetched data and the data has been set to the `data` hook. How can I do it?

edit: I need the data before rendering the components.

```
export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData]

  useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("/data").then((res) => setData(res.data)).catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <Home />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like as below

```
export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("/data").then((res) => setData(res.data)).catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <Home setData={setData}/> //here you can pass data to the home component and play with the data
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention that I use react-router and that's why I need the data before rendering the routes. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: oh ok, you need to render home component after you got the data right?

Comment: What I'm saying is that I need data before rendering:  return (
    <div>
      <Home setData={setData}/>
    </div>
  ). @EnigmaState

Comment: yes the data is stored in `setData` variable so you can access from that variable before return

Comment: But then {return} renders twice.

Comment: may i know the reason why you need the data apart from sending data to `home` component

Comment: Calling axios API in client side rendering will made the component render twice, because API return is async and will finish undefinitely. Instead, you can use a server-side render options, similar with getInitialProps / getStaticProps in NextJs (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps)

Answer (score 2):

You can conditionally render a component based on a state. That way it only exists when the state is not null.

```js
export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("/data").then((res) => setData(res.data)).catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {data ? <Home setData={setData}/> : null } // here you can pass data to the home component
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an if statement before the render to check if your data has not been loaded into the state yet, so, you can return null if you do not want the component to render.

```
export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/data")
      .then((response) => setData(response.data))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
  }, [])

  if (data === null) return null

  return (
    <div>
      <Home />
    </div>
  )
}
```